# return node if a node has an outgoing relation to the same value case insensitive

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My structure is I have nodes that have many relation to different properties. 
The problem is: somethimes nodes have the same property multiple times.

```
(n)-[]->(value:YEllow) and (n)-[]->(value:yellow)
```

And I would like to find where this happens.
I don't know what properties are connected to a node so i can't WHERE n.value=~ '(?i).*', distinct also does not work.

Comment: the answer could be  Match(n)
with lower(n.name) as lower ,n
return count(n), count(distinct(lower)) 
and then i can see the difference in count

Comment: The notation you're providing uses Cypher's syntax for labels. So what exactly has mixed upper/lower case? Property keys, labels or property values? If you're talking about property values, the comment above is the answer.

Comment: it is the property not the labels